# Размер массива должен ввести пользователь

Tags: c

Как реализовать ввод размера массива пользователем в Си? Нужно ли при этом пользоваться указателями ?

Comment: На этот вопрос отвечали множество раз.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka,можете написать,как ?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka так найдите подходящий ответ и закройте как дубликат!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *a;  // указатель на int для массива
    int i, n;

    printf("Введите размер массива: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // Выделение памяти
    a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    // Ввод элементов массива
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    // Вывод элементов массива
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    free(a);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Уже решил проблему , но спасибо

Comment: `int *a` - это не указатель на массив, а указатель на `int`. Указатель на массив это, например, `int (*a)[3]`.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov первый раз вижу такую запись. Есть где почитать про неё подробнее?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov хотя возникло подозрение, что это не указатель на массив, а массив указателей - штука малополезная и потому ранее мной не виденная

Comment: @andreymal, это указатель на массив. Действительно редко применяется. Массив указателей: `char *argv[]` - правда никогда такого не видели?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov всегда считал `*argv[]` и `**argv` одним и тем же - указателем на первый элемент массива указателей на первые элементы массивов знаковых целых чисел. Где можно почитать про то, что запись `foo[]` - непосредственно массив, а не указатель?

Comment: @andreymal, где почитать - сходу не скажу, но попробуйте что-нибудь присвоить этому `foo[]` чтобы убедиться, что это не одно и то же с `*foo`.

Comment: Блин, это уже только поздно вечером, я не у компа. Однако абсолютно каждый виденный мной учебник по Си меня уверял, что `foo[]` и `*foo` - абсолютно одно и то же.

Comment: @andreymal, одно и то же, когда это объявление аргумента функции. А если это объявление переменных, то массив и указатель - разные вещи https://ideone.com/tp24NH#cmperr то есть с моей стороны действительно неудачный пример был.

Comment: @andreymal, когда вы объявляете аргумент функции как массив, C неявно подменяет тип на указатель. §6.7.5.7 [отсюда](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: @AlexanderZonov пример действительно неудачный, так как `foo[]` в теле функции, оказывается, вообще не компилируется :) `int (*a)[3]` судя по компилятору и правда указатель на массив, это мозговыносящее удивление для меня, буду знать ._. (ещё одна в копилку причин, почему следует кодить на Rust, а не Си)

Answer (score 2):

Стандарт Си допускает объявление автоматических массивов с переменной длиной<sup>1</sup>, GCC поддерживает это в качестве расширения и для С++<sup>2</sup>.

Пример:

```
int length = 1;
scanf("%d", &length);
double array[length];
...
```

Из плюсов решения стоит отметить простоту использования и отсутствие необходимости явно освобождать память - такой массив будет уничтожен сразу после выхода из области видимости, где он был объявлен.

Из минусов - память для такого массива выделяется на стеке, а в некоторых системах его размер может быть ограничен. Впрочем, в Unix изменить эту настройку можно командой `ulimit -s unlimited`.

> Нужно ли при этом пользоваться указателями?

Как видите, это не обязательно ;-)

<sup>1</sup> после создания менять размер уже не получится
<sup>2</sup> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: Будет работать только внутри функции, поскольку такие массивы резервируются в стеке. Тем не менее, это на самом деле лучший ответ, автор вопроса выбрал неправильно.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Из-за того, что место резервируется на стеке, этот самый стек может и переполниться. Поэтому такими массивами надо пользоваться с большой осторожностью. Так что, по-моему, автор вопроса ответ выбрал правильно (не этот).